# ASP .Net Video Player (AVI)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a way to play video files over the net.  Essentially I have some AVI files that will be on the server that will be loaded dynamically on certain controls.  They're presentation & help files to help educate people about the choices they're making, and will appear in a div section in a table.

It's 2008 Server / IIS 7 / ASP .Net 4.0

I was trying to avoid flash/silverlight/active x if at all possible  (essentially anything that will make the user do anything extra).
Anyone have any source or relevant links?  Page is in VB but I'm familiar with c# so either will work.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you convert then to say h264, then you can use vanilla HTML5 <video> with flash fallback E.g. http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: You can use FFmpeg to encode your video files to h.264 like Alex suggested. http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: If the site is public then you should evaluate publishing the videos on youtube - you will save bandwidth costs etc.

Comment: im working on project called www.cloudeyes.tv its all about security camera's so those videos are highly confidential, first i need show my head that .avi format file gonna play in a video player dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Can try doing it in plain HTML, either using video tags if HTML is an option.

I am playing avi files in a project I am working on by using `<object>` tags with fallbacks for when they do not work.  Note, this does not do anything HTML5 as this is not an option for me, you can add this before the below code though.

```
'<object data="' + fileUri + '" type="video/x-ms-wmv" class="preview-container" classid="clsid:E23FE9C6-778E-49D4-B537-38FCDE4887D8" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"> 
       <param name="src" value="' + fileUri + '" > 
       <param name="loop" value="true" > 
       <param name="controller" value="true" > 
       <param name="autoplay" value="true">
       <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="' + fileUri + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"> 
               <param name="controller" value="true" > 
               <param name="loop" value="true" > 
               <param name="autoplay" value="true"> 
               <a href="' + fileUri + '">Download</a> 
        </object> 
 </object>'
```

Essentially how I handle this is dynamically change the fileUri parameter via javascript to retrieve different videos.  This will try and play the video, and if both method fail, then it will show a download link.  The first `<object>` tag is for IE, and the second for other browser.  IE requires you to provide a classid to the player you are using.  The classid here is for VLC, but this can be changed to whatever you want to use, e.g. Windows Media Player.

EDIT: Due to your comment, if your link is static then you can hardcode the URI:

```
<object data="PUT-YOUR-URI-HERE" type="video/x-ms-wmv" classid="clsid:E23FE9C6-778E-49D4-B537-38FCDE4887D8"> 
       <param name="src" value="PUT-YOUR-URI-HERE" > 
       <param name="loop" value="true" > 
       <param name="controller" value="true" > 
       <param name="autoplay" value="true">
       <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="PUT-YOUR-URI-HERE"> 
               <param name="controller" value="true" > 
               <param name="loop" value="true" > 
               <param name="autoplay" value="true"> 
               <a href="PUT-YOUR-URI-HERE">Download</a> 
        </object> 
 </object>
```

Comment: http://localhost:2216/Cloudeyes/vids/Eknovate_20121227125134_1.Avi   This is my video path i don't know where to give this? in code to play video

Comment: replace the fileUri variable with your file path then

Comment: I'm not getting it dear.. help me.. i can see red underlined query when i give my path